# How to cancel "Update Reminder" for Smartgit?

Tags: smartgit

I bought a perpetual license for Smartgit 21 and did not shut of the "Automatically download new updates." Now Smartgit is popping up "Install new update?" notifications for 22, which I don't want because I'd have to buy it.

I change my setting to "Do not check for new updates" but how to I stop the reminder to install the one it downloaded?